# Getting the indices of n highest items before a tage value

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a list of temperatures, and I need to find *n* values before and after the desired temperature, preferably in separate lists.The values in my list are not necessarily unique, but I need the **index** of the original list. I need these indices to find other parameters in other lists.

Example:

```
TestArray = np.array([12,42,19,32,41,14,17,23,12,18,32,19])
Value = 20
n = 2
TestArray = np.append(TestArray, Value) 
Sort = np.argsort(TestArray)
Index = np.where(Sort == (len(TestArray)-1))[0][0]
Lower = Sort[Index-n:Index]
Upper = Sort[Index+1:Index+n+1]
print(Upper, TestArray[Upper])
print(Lower, TestArray[Lower])
```

My code gives the wanted output, but it looks really messy and I was wondering if there was a better way.

Explanation:
I append the wanted value to the end, so I know its index. Then I use *argsort* find the indices from low to high, and then use np.where to locate where my wanted value is. Then use indexing to find upper and lower values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the array and then use [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
mask = TestArray < Value
Lower, Upper = -np.partition(-TestArray[mask], 2)[:2], np.partition(TestArray[~mask], 2)[:2]

Lower
#array([19, 19])

Upper
#array([23, 32])
```

To get the indices back:

```
TestArray = np.array([12,42,19,32,41,14,17,23,12,18,32,19])    ​
​
mask = TestArray < Value
arrInd = np.column_stack((np.arange(len(TestArray)), TestArray))
Lower, Upper = arrInd[mask,:], arrInd[~mask,:]
LowerInd, UpperInd = np.argpartition(-Lower[:, 1], 2)[:2], np.argpartition(Upper[:,1], 2)[:2]
​
print(Lower[LowerInd])
​#[[ 2 19]
# [11 19]]

print(Upper[UpperInd])
#[[ 7 23]
# [ 3 32]]
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to get the indices of these elements? I believe np.partition only returns True or False (in this setup) Maybe I should make this more clear in the question as well.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me the much desired indices.

Answer (score 0):

I think `np.searchsorted` may be of use to you.

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
>>> np.searchsorted([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The *numpy* solutions are likely the best way to go.  For comparison, here is a somewhat efficient solution using [*heapq.nsmallest()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> data = [12,42,19,32,41,14,17,23,12,18,32,19]
>>> nsmallest(2, data, key=lambda x: (x-20 if x >= 20 else float('inf')))
[23, 32]
>>> nsmallest(2, data, key=lambda x: (20-x if x <= 20 else float('inf')))
[19, 19]
```